# Can't pass HOST header in request

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http, http-headers

Is it possible to send HOST header in request, because I'm trying to do it but it throwing me an error

> Refused to set unsafe header "Host"

I'm trying to do it in Angular 5 with HTTP Interceptor

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.apiService.kcs.client().token}`,
            Host: 'servercore.docker.localhost'
        },
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

The `Authorization` header is being sent in while the `Host` is being sent same as URL and is not being sent as i provided. So its failing to to overwrite it.

Comment: Looks like it's Chrome that blocks setting that header, not Angular, so not sure if there's much you can do

Comment: @user184994 do you think that there is anything that can help me pass this issue?

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to change the `Host` header?

Comment: @user184994 I am using TRAEFIK for my requests to go through, so in order for TRAEFIK to work properly and to know where to pass the request I need to send a HOST header